# How to Render a Button, each with Different Background Colors in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, background-color, react-component

I have a button component containing its style and content. What I want to do is to render the button with different background colors every after the button component is called and will about to generate the button itself. My problem is that I am not sure which way should I do in order to render a different background color for every button rendered. Should I use a given array of colors and loop it to the button's bgcolor everytime the button component is called to ensure a different color for each button rendered?

Even after passing a backgroundColor prop to the button component via sx. It doesn't seem to work as of the moment, that's why I decided to utilize an array for the colors to loop on if possible.

Goal appearance when the button component is called and rendered a button:
[image: Goal appearance]

Source code for button component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function ItemsCategoryButton({ title, price, availables}) {

  const buttonColors = [
    "#402C2C",
    "#402C3D",
    "#392C40",
    "#2C3740",
    "#2C403D",
    "#2C4035",
    "#31402C",
    "#3D402C",
    "#40392C",
    "#402C2C",
    "#402C3D",
    "#2C3740",
    "#2C4035",
    "#3D402C",
    "#402C2C",
  ];

  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      className="itemButton"
      sx={{
        display: "block",
        mt: -3.8,
        ml: 1,
        width: 160,
        height: 115,
        textTransform: "none",
        borderRadius: 3,
        bgcolor:buttonColors[6] //just a test sample to access the array of colors if I should do a for loop on it

      
      }}
    >
      <Typography sx={{ fontFamily: "Barlow Condensed", fontSize: "20px" }}>
        {title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography sx={{ fontFamily: "Barlow Condensed", fontSize: "14px" }}>
        Php {price}
      </Typography>
      <Typography sx={{ fontFamily: "Barlow Condensed", fontSize: "14px" }}>
        {availables} available
      </Typography>
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Source code when button component is called:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ItemsCategoryButton from "./ItemsCategoryButton";

export default function MultipleButtons() {
  return (
   
      <ItemsCategoryButton
          title="Buffalo Wings"
          price="200.00"
          availables="20"   
        />
        <ItemsCategoryButton
          title="Battered Chicken (Half)"
          price="195.00"
          availables="20"
        />
        <ItemsCategoryButton
          title="Battered Chicken (Whole)"
          price="380.00"
          availables="20"
        />
        <ItemsCategoryButton
          title="Garlic Chicken (Half)"
          price="210.00"
          availables="20"
        />

        <ItemsCategoryButton
          title="Garlic Chicken (Whole)"
          price="400.00"
          availables="20"
        />
   
  );
}
```

Source code to display:

```
import "./styles.css";
import MultipleButtons from "./MultipleButtons";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MultipleButtons />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your responses would help me a lot as I am exploring MUI as of this moment.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: why do you want it to be random everytime instead of passing the BG color as a prop?

Comment: I want the buttons to have different bgcolors. You mean I should implement the BG colors as a prop or change it into something different?

Comment: buttons will have different BG colors, depending on what color you pass as a prop